# mapping a smaller matrix in a greater matrix with a specific sequence

Tags: matrix

I have a matrix   300x300  i need to map the values  ina greater matrix (900x900) in  the positions given by the sequence 
$$({3*i-1,3*j-1)}$$
 while everything else remain empty, how can achieve this result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**KroneckerProduct**

```
f5 = KroneckerProduct[#, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}] &;
f6 = KroneckerProduct[SparseArray@#, SparseArray[{2, 2} -> 1, {3, 3}]] &;
```

**SparseArray and Band**

```
f1 = SparseArray[Band[{2, 2}, Automatic, {3, 3}] -> #,3 Dimensions[#]] &;
```

or

```
f1 = SparseArray[Band[{2, 2}, 3 Dimensions[#], {3, 3}] -> #] &
```

**ArrayFlatten and ArrayPad**

```
f2 = ArrayFlatten[Map[ArrayPad[{{#}}, 1] &, #, {2}]] &;
```

**Examples**

```
n = 3;
m = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, {n, n}];
Row[MatrixForm /@ {m, f1@m, f2@m}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

**Timings:**

```
f0 = (* from bill's answer *) SparseArray[Flatten[{Drop[ArrayRules@ SparseArray[#] /. 
      {x_, y_} -> {3 x - 1, 3 y - 1}, -1], 3 Dimensions[#] -> 0}, 1]] &;

f3 = (* from george2079's answer *) SparseArray[{i_ /; Mod[i + 1, 3] == 0, 
      j_ /; Mod[j + 1, 3] == 0} :> #[[(i + 1)/3, (j + 1)/3]], {3 Length@#, 3 Length@#}] &;

f4 = (* from ciao's answer *) Upsample[#, 3, 2] &;

n = 300; mm = RandomInteger[10, {n, n}];

Equal @@ Through[{f0, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6}[mm]]
```

> True

```
Grid[SortBy[{HoldForm[#], First@AbsoluteTiming[#[mm]]} & /@ 
     {f0, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6}, Last], Dividers -> All] // Style[#, 16, Bold, "Panel"] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: it works thanks but i  fail at understanding  the  code, i am just a novice. same thing  with bill's answer. what does the & and the # means?

Comment: @Alucard, `f1 = SparseArray[Band[{2, 2}, Automatic, {3, 3}] -> #,3 Dimensions[#]] &;` is the same as `f1[mat_] : = SparseArray[Band[{2, 2}, Automatic, {3, 3}] ->mat,3 Dimensions[mat]] ;` see [Function (&)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) and [Slot (#)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Slot.html) in the docs.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps I'm missing something in the question, but why not just:

```
new=Upsample[old, 3, 2];
```

Comment: god i have no words, i  did not know there was this command

Comment: @Alucard - Developing a full vocabulary of Mathematica functions is probably on the order of developing a decent vocabulary in English - I doubt there are many that know *all* of the functions off the tops of their heads...

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way -- represent the original array in sparse form, then replace the indices with the desired ones:

```
m = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {3, 3}];
Normal@SparseArray[Drop[ArrayRules@SparseArray[m] 
            /. {x_, y_} -> {3 x - 1, 3 y - 1}, -1]] // MatrixForm
```

More generally, and controlling for the ultimate size of the matrix:

```
n = 3; m = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, {n, n}];
Normal@SparseArray[Flatten[{Drop[ArrayRules@SparseArray[m] 
     /. {x_, y_} -> {3 x - 1, 3 y - 1}, -1], {3 n, 3 n} -> 0}, 1]]
```

Comment: I think the dimensions of the resulting matrix should be `{3 n, 3 n}` (not `{n^2,n^2}`).

Comment: @kglr - Thanks for noticing... just fooled by the simple n=3 case where 3n==n^2!

Answer (score 1):

A different `SparseArray` approach:

```
n = 3
(m = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, {n, n}]) // MatrixForm
big = SparseArray[ 
     {i_ /; Mod[i + 1, 3] == 0, j_ /; Mod[j + 1, 3] == 0} :>
      #[[(i + 1)/3, (j + 1)/3]] , {3 Length@#, 3 Length@#}] &@m;
MatrixForm[big]
```